# Gradle: Library project dependent library could not be found in Application project using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have library1  that is referencing library2. Now when I reference library 1 in my application, library2 is not found. It gives me error that :Library2:SecondLibraySDK could not be found  in project :..:Library1:FirstLibrarySDK.

Library1 is working absolutely fine. The problem appears when I add it in my application.

I have looked at many problems but still having the issue

[Android Gradle build with sub projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971375/android-gradle-build-with-sub-projects)

[Gradle subproject not included in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371633/gradle-subproject-not-included-in-classpath)

Here is my folder structure:

```
MYApplication
->build.gradle
->app
    -> build.gradle

Library1 
->build.gradle
->FirstLibrarySDK
    -> build.gradle

Library2
->build.gradle
->SecondLibrarySDK
    -> build.gradle
```

setting.gradle of MyApplication

```
'..:Library1:FirstLibrarySDK'
```

setting.gradle of Library1

```
'..:Library2:SecondLibrarySDK'
```

This is gradlew projects of my library:

```
Root project 'Library1'
+--- Project ':..'
|    \--- Project ':..:Library2'
|         \--- Project ':..:SecondLibrarySDK'
\--- Project ':FirstLibrarySDK'
```

Comment: Is your project Libray or Library? (Notice the missing r)

Comment: I have edited my question. My library is working fine. The issue appears when I am adding my library in the application.